# Path params vs query params when the endpoints are very similar

Tags: java, spring, rest, api, web-services

I am currently developing a REST API that exposes different endpoints.

An example of such an endpoint is

```
/users/{userId}/transactions/type/{transactionType}/all
```

This endpoint returns a list of all transactions of a specific transaction type of a user.

I also have an endpoint for retrieving all transactions of a specific category from a user, which would be accessed by this endpoint

```
/users/{userId}/transactions/category/{categoryId}/all
```

My question is would this be a good approach or is it better to have one endpoint and have optional query params?

For example

```
/users/{userId}/transactions/all?categoryId={id}&transactionType={type}

/users/{userId}/transactions/all?categoryId={id}

/users/{userId}/transactions/all?transactionType={type}

/users/{userId}/transactions/all
```

The benefit of the latter is that you would be able to filter your transactions on category and type, instead of just one. But would that be a good design or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a good approach to have query params to filter transactions.
But to follow the idea of REST it would be better if you change the endpoints.

from

```
/users/{userId}/transactions/type/{transactionType}/all
```

to

```
/users/{userId}/transactions?transactionType={transactionType}
```

From the endpoint you can read following:
the query would return for user with value userid all transactions with transactionType.
So the values that will be returned by query should stay at the end of the endpoint and all filters are query parameters.In your case the query return transactions, so transactions are at the end and then query parameters.

And you don't need the word 'all' in the REST endpoint.

```
/users/{userId}/transactions?categoryId={id}&transactionType={type}
```

Answer (score 0):

REST offers no guidance on URI design, other than the fact that your identifiers should be compliant with [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A).

```
/x/y/z
/x?y=z
```

Both of those identifiers are *fine*.

A URI with application/x-www-form-urlencoded key-value pairs has the advantage that web browsers have a standard for HTML form processing.  The form acts as a sort of [URI Template](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570).

Path segments are convenient when you have an identifier hierarchy to navigate, because the URI standard includes [relative resolution](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2) and dot segments.

In REST, identifiers are functionally opaque - general purpose clients don't extract any semantic information from the URI.  That gives the server freedom to encode any information it wants into the identifiers.

Which means that, for your own resources, you can choose any URI design that you like.  The most common choices focus on something that is easy for routing (in whatever server implementation you happen to choose) and conforming to your local design standards (in this way, URI are a lot like variable names -- the compiler/interpreter doesn't care, but the human being performing code review does care).

See [Stefan Tilkov's 2014 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pspy1H6A3FM).